# Best style to use multiple custom UserControls in a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following:

A MainWindow;

with Children on the MainGrid in the MainWindow:

- ContentControl, displays the main content of the program and has a taskbar at the bottom for user interaction
- AddContentControl, shall be started via ContentControl, a control that allows the user to add content to the ContentControl
- TakePictureControl, shall be started from AddContentControl, allows the user to take a picture via webcam
- CropControl, shall be started from TakePictureControl after the Picture was taken, because the image has to be square
- SettingsControl, shall be started from ContentControl, allows to change the settings of the program

So basically I have the following hierarchy:
MainWindow<-MainGrid<-The five controls, only one visible at a time

Since controls are childs of the MainGrid/Window, I can't access the initialized objects of the control.

What I want is the following:

- Stay in one window
- access a control from another control
- pass arguments to a control from another control (e.g. image from TakePhotoControl to CropControl)
- code that is easy to understand and object oriented

What I had earlier was that I did not encapsulate the controls, so I had the main logic in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and all UI elements sitting directly on the MainGrid. Positive was that I could access everything I wanted. Negative is that this was horrible to read (and it will get worse), not comfortable to edit, not object oriented and barely reusable.

How do I solve my issue?

Comment: consider [edit]ing to help readers understand how this question differs from [one you asked at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218326/interaction-with-multiple-controls)

Comment: What? It IS the same question, since someone suggested that I get a decent answer here and not on stackoverflow. I now deleted the question on stackoverflow to eleminate the redundancy. @gnat

Comment: same question? that's no good. ["Cross-posting is frowned upon..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) Whoever advised you, they gave bad idea. Correct approach when question is a better fit at some other site is to flag for moderator to [migrate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/migration/info)

Comment: Thats why I deleted the question at stack overflow, so there is non cross posting anymore. I thought I had to rephrase my question so I did not use the same text as in the now deleted question from yesterday. 
So back to topic please